# Apache Common Maths - Univariate Function Solver

Tags: java, apache-commons-math

I am trying to solve the following mathematical equation for "V" using the apache-commons-math solver.

Equation :

V = log(X/ (V-1))

Following is the MWE;

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.UnivariateFunction;
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.solvers.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UnivariateFunction function = v ->  v - Math.log( (9/(v-1)) );
        UnivariateSolver solver = new BrentSolver();
        double c = solver.solve(100, function, -10.0, 10.0, 0);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error;

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.math3.exception.NoBracketingException: function values at endpoints do not have different signs, endpoints: [-10, 10], values: [�, 10]

I have looked around the internet to solve it but so far no success. I am looking for an MWE to solve "V", any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BrentSolver` only works with univariate functions over the real numbers.  The real number support for the function `f(v) = v - log(c / (v - 1))` is `(1, Infinity)`.  If v is less than or equal to 1, then the function evaluates to a complex number.

The solver is failing because it tries to evaluate the function at -10 and receives `NaN` at the value.  This causes the bracketing exception to occur because the sign of `NaN` is indeterminate.

So, in order for the solver to work you must provide an initial lower bound that is included in the real number support.  Something just greater than 1 should suffice.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it solved the problem